# Proving that if $p_{n}$ converges then $|p_{n}| $ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-verification

**EDIT1:** Prove using the definition of a converging sequence in a metric space, that the convergence of the sequence $\left \{ p_{n} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ implies the convergence of the sequence $\left \{ |p_{n}| \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $|p_{n}|$ denotes the absolute value of $p_{n}$.

**EDIT2:** *Definition of a convergent sequence*. A sequence $\left \{ p_{n} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to be convergent if there exists $p \in X$ with the following property:

For all $\epsilon>0$, there is a $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N(\epsilon)$ implies $d(p_{n},p) < \epsilon$.

**EDIT3:** Suppose $\left \{ p_{n} \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $p$. We claim that  $\left \{ |p_{n}| \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $|p|$.

So for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N(\epsilon)$ such that $n \geq N(\epsilon) \Rightarrow ||p_{n}|-|p|| \leq |p_{n} -p| < \epsilon$ since $p_{n} \rightarrow  p$.

So $\left \{ |p_{n}| \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $|p|$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Could  you  use  the  continuity  of  the  $|\ \  |$  function ?

Comment: Why $d(|p_n|,p)=d(p_n,p)<\varepsilon?$

Comment: For a general metric space, what would $\lvert p_n\rvert$ mean?

Comment: I don't think it's for a general metric space, maybe a normed space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is incorrect. Even your definitions are sloppy. First of all, in a metric space, there is no such thing as "the absolute value" of an element. But let's say that you mean some sort of norm.

$$\{|p_n|\}_{n=1}^\infty$$ is a sequence of real numbers and converges to a real number, $p$ is not necesarily a real number. So, the value $d(|p_n|, p)$ is not even defined.

---

Even if the value is defined (so if your original metric space is $\mathbb R$), you can take

$$\forall n: p_n = -1$$

and the sequence obviously converges to $p=-1$, however the sequence $$\{|p_n|\}_{n=1}^\infty$$ does **not** converge to $-1$.

---

EDIT:

You made a mistake when you wrote down $$||p_n| - p| = |p_n - p|$$

That equality does not hold for negative values of $p_n$.

Your real mistake is trying to prove that $|p_n|$ converges to $p$. You can find examples, like

$$-1,-1,-1,\dots$$

in which the limit of $p_n$ is equal to $p=-1$, but the series $|p_n|$ is equal to $$1,1,1,\dots$$ and does not converge to $p$ at all.

Comment: @OGC If you found the task in some book, you could just write the question as it is written in the book...

Comment: The question is in the very first para of my post. Yes, but I can't use a general metric space.

Comment: @OGC And, as I already explained, the question is not well defined. It's like asking what is the color of a bumblehubaloo. If you don't tell me what a bumblehubaloo is, then I can't answer the question, and nobody else can either.

Comment: Quote: `you could just write the question as it is written in the book`.

Comment: @OGC In the book, it does not say "I want to prove, using the...". You obviously did not quote the book directly. If you give the exact question your book asked, we may be able to clear your confusion. Right now, the question **you** are asking is mathematically nonsensical. I don't know what the question **the book** is asking is.

Comment: It's not from the book. I've made an edit and the first para is exactly what the instructor wrote.

Comment: So if the result isn't even true then I have to inform my instructor.

Comment: @OGC It's not that the result is true or false. It's that you are missing a part of your definition. Is the question meant to be asked in **any** metric space? If so, what is the definition of $|p_n|$ when $p_n$ is in this metric space?

Comment: He didn't mention anything about the metric space. Doesn't it hold in real space? I'll also make an edit about what definition of convergence was used in class.

Comment: @OGC It holds in the real space if you define the standard metric and $|x|$ to mean the absolute value. But then your proof is wrong, as my counterexample (of all $-1$) shows.

Comment: Think my latest may clear the confusion.

Comment: @OGC I added an edit to my answer which I think you should read.

Comment: I see. So basically how do I prove the statement in EDIT1?

Comment: @OGC You need to find the correct limit point. For example, take the sequence of $-1$-es. What do it's absolute values converge to and how is that related to the limit of the original sequence?

Comment: See my latest edit for verification, please.

Comment: @OGC Looks alright now, yeah :)

Comment: You can also upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. Take sequence $p_n=-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$ with usual metric.
But if $p_n\to p$ then $|p_n|\to |p|$ because $||p_n|-|p||\leqslant |p_n-p|$ if $X=\mathbb{R}^1$ with usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$